# Haskell How to rewrite a code using fold-function?

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, histogram, fold

I want to rewrite (or upgrade! :) ) my two functions, `hist` and `sort`, using fold-functions. But since I am only in the beginning of my Haskell-way, I can't figure out how to do it.

First of all, I have defined `Insertion`, `Table` and imported `Data.Char`:

```
type Insertion = (Char, Int)
type Table = [Insertion]
import Data.Char
```

Then I have implemented the following code for `hist`:

```
hist :: String -> Table
hist[] = []
hist(x:xs) = sortBy x (hist xs) where
    sortBy x [] = [(x,1)]
    sortBy x ((y,z):yzs)
      | x == y = (y,z+1) : yzs 
      | otherwise = (y,z) : sortBy x yzs
```

And this one for `sort`:

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort [] = []
sort (x:xs) = paste x (sort xs)

paste :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
paste y [] = [y]
paste y (x:xs)
    | x < y = x : paste y xs 
    | otherwise = y : x : xs
```

What can I do next? How can I use the fold-functions to implement them?

Comment: `sort` looks like it could just be `foldr paste []`. What does `hist` do?

Comment: @user: I think it calculates the frequency of each `Char` of the string. It can be implemented with `foldr` as well.

Comment: Your `sortBy` function doesn't need its first parameter, since `x` is always the same. However, if you extract it outside as it is, you will see how `hist` can be refactored to a `foldr` the same way as `sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foldr f z` on a list replaces the "cons" of the list `(:)` with `f` and the empty list `[]` with `z`.

This thus means that for a list like `[1,4,2,5]`, we thus obtain `f 1 (f 4 (f 2 (f 5 z)))`, since `[1,4,2,5]` is short for `1 : 4 : 2 : 5 : []` or more canonical `(:) 1 ((:) 4 ((:) 2 ((:) 5 [])))`.

The `sort` function for example can be replaced with a fold function:

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort = foldr paste []
```

since `sort [1,4,2,5]` is equivalent to `paste 1 (paste 4 (paste 2 (paste 5 [])))`. Here `f` thus takes as first parameter an element, and as second parameter the result of calling `foldr f z` on the rest of the list,

I leave `hist` as an exercise.